# Customized Camera view in ZXING code reader to show detection

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am using the ZXING QR Code Reader. It is working fine. Detecting codes etc but it does not shows any detection progress(Like red line) while it is scanning the QR Code. Here is Screenshot

[image]

And my ScanActivity is,

ScanCode.Java

```
public class ScanCode extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnScan;
TextView scanResult;
String text;
Bitmap bmp;
ImageView ivPic;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.scan_code);
    initViews();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnScanCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}

private void initViews() {
    scanResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanResult);
    ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capturedImg);
    btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScanCode);
    btnScan.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contents,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            scanResult.setText(contents);
        }// if result_ok
}// onActivityResult
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is bit late but I've just used Zxing barcode/QR-Code scanner recently in my app, if anyone has issue implementing it just follow the steps below (Using Android Studio Official IDE for android).

First add dependencies in `app --> build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
      compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
      compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

**Activity Usage:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnScan;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
        btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                   scanBarcode();

              }

        });
    }

    private void scanBarcode()
    {
        new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            if(result.getContents() == null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

If you want to use custom `callback` and BarCodeView. Zxing provide this functionality simply make layout file

```
<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView>

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScanResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scan Results will be shown here"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

In Activity use the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

CompoundBarcodeView barcodeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        barcodeView = (CompoundBarcodeView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
        barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);
        barcodeView.setStatusText("");

     }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        barcodeView.resume();

        isScanned = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        barcodeView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        return barcodeView.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result)
        {
            if (result.getText() != null)
            {
                barcodeView.setStatusText(result.getText());

                tvscanResult.setText("Data found: " + result.getText());

            }

            //you can also Add preview of scanned barcode
            //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.barcodePreview);
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(result.getBitmapWithResultPoints(Color.YELLOW));
        }

        @Override
        public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints)
        {
            System.out.println("Possible Result points = " + resultPoints);
        }
    };
}
```

Source [zxing-android-embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded). Hope someone get help from this solution